# Snippet from Cucumber Java TestNG looks strange

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, bdd

I am trying Cucumber for my Selenium Java + TestNG project.
Once I run the .feature file with empty stepdefinition, I should get a snippet that I can just copy paste to my step definition class. But I got a strange format that can't be used out of the box.

`Given` should be `@Given` , right? 
There is no `public void()` .

What could be the cause?  Thank You.

```js
2 Scenarios (2 undefined)
5 Steps (5 undefined)
0m0.000s
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
Given("^User is on Home Page$", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
});
When("^User enters UserName and Password$", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
});
Then("^He can visit the practice page$", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
});
When("^User LogOut from the Application$", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
});
Then("^he cannot visit practice page$", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
});
```

This is my `glue file`

```js
package glue;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
@Test(groups = "cucumber")
@CucumberOptions(features = "C:\\Users\\workspace\\cucumber\\src\\test\\java\\feature\\logintest.feature", 
glue = "C:\\Users\\workspace\\cucumber\\src\\test\\java\\glue\\Glue.java", 
plugin = {"html:C:\\Users\\workspace\\cucumber\\logs"})
 
public class Glue extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Features")
    public void runCukes() throws IOException {
        
    }
}
```

This is my `.feature` file

```js
Feature: Login
Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
Given User is on Home Page
When User enters UserName and Password
Then He can visit the practice page
Scenario: Successful LogOut
When User LogOut from the Application
Then he cannot visit practice page
```

This is my dependencies

```js
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using cucumber-java8 dependency, for that below is the format for stepDefintion file(make sure your java compiler version should be 1.8).

@Given Annotation will be in cucumber-java

Given Annotation will be in cucumber-java8

```
import cucumber.api.java8.En;

public class stepDefinitions implements En{

public stepDefinitions(){
    Given("^User is on Home Page$", () -> {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.println("Test1");
    });

    When("^User enters UserName and Password$", () -> {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.println("Test2");
    });

    Then("^He can visit the practice page$", () -> {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.println("Test3");
    });

    When("^User LogOut from the Application$", () -> {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.println("Test4");
    });

    Then("^he cannot visit practice page$", () -> {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.println("Test5");
    });
   }
 }
```

I executed it in my machine its working, try it and let me know if it works for you.

Link for reference:
http://codoid.com/cucumber-lambda-expressions/